# docker.io - Connecting to MySQL with Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, docker

I am new to Docker. Currently, I am trying to connect my Scala container with a MySQL container but just can't find any resources on how I can do it. Is it able for me to create a JDBC connection on the Scala container and connect to the MySQL container using the linking method?

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#docker-container-linking 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/wildflyjavaee7-and-mysql-linked-on-two-docker-containers-tech-tip-65.html

Comment: What's the problem?  It's definitely possible (I've done it) but without specific information on the issue you've run into it's hard to help.

Comment: The issue is that I do not know how to add a JDBC driver into the Scala's image that is build via Dockerfile & run it so that when I use the linking method to link my application container to my DB container. It will be able to connect and access the data from it.

Comment: Did you add the driver to your SBT build file?

Answer (score 0):

mysql runs on a port.The default port for this is 3306.
This port on your mysql container should be exposed by adding **EXPOSE 3306** in dockerfile.
For best results use official mysql image from docker hub (https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ )

use **-h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR"**  in your scala container.
Eg: mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -u -p

This should do the trick!!